# Writing a file in /proc continuouly floods the dmesg

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am trying to read/Write a variable in the linux kernel module using /proc file entry facility.
Kernel module compiles successfully but when tried writing it via

```
echo 1 > My_file
```

This operation didn't finish.

Also, dmesg console is continuously flooded with some random value.

```
[ 1171.481231] proc_write_flag New_Flag 1124646486
[ 1171.481245] proc_write_flag New_Flag 1124646486
[ 1171.481259] proc_write_flag New_Flag 1124646486
[ 1171.481271] proc_write_flag New_Flag 1124646486
[ 1171.481473] ^C
```

I am new to linux device drivers and trying to use `/proc` facility provided by the linux kernel. I tried removing the this kernel module, but again, the **operation didn't finish**.

what is causing this behaviour and how can i rectify it?

Here is the code:

```
int my_flag;
static struct proc_dir_entry *pdir = NULL;

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("GPL");

static ssize_t proc_read_flag(struct file* page,char __user * data, size_t count, loff_t *offset);
static ssize_t proc_write_flag(struct file *file, const char __user* ubuf, size_t count, loff_t* offset);

static struct file_operations myops = 
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = proc_read_flag,
    .write= proc_write_flag,
};


//ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
//Updated Read function after the reply.
    static ssize_t proc_read_flag(struct file* page,char __user * data, size_t count,loff_t *offset)
{
    int ret;
    if( count >my_flag)         //my_flag holds the count of chars received by write function.
            count = my_flag;
    ret = copy_to_user(data, my_buf, my_flag );
     printk("%s: ret = %d ,my_flag %d\n",__FUNCTION__, ret, my_flag);
    return ( my_flag - ret );
}


//ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
//Updated Write function After the reply.
static ssize_t proc_write_flag(struct file *file, const char __user* ubuf, size_t count, loff_t* offset)
{

    if( copy_from_user(my_buf,ubuf,count) ){        //Returns No. of bytes could not copy
            return -EFAULT;
    }
    my_flag = count;
    printk("%s New_Flag %d Data: %s\n",__FUNCTION__,my_flag,my_buf);
    return count;
}

int init_module(void)
{
    struct proc_dir_entry *pfile = NULL;

    pdir = proc_mkdir("My_dir",NULL);
    if(!pdir){
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    pfile = proc_create("My_file", 0666, pdir, &myops);
    if(!pfile)
        return -ENOMEM;


    printk("Proc_entry Created Successfully, Module initialized\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_function(void)
{
    remove_proc_entry("My_file", pdir);
    remove_proc_entry("My_dir", NULL);
    printk("Removing Proc_entry!!!");
}
```

Comment: Write is working fine but, But when i read the device, it is continuously printing the same old data and flooding the dmesg.

Comment: Read again what `proc_read_flag` function actually does - not what you think you made it do, but what it actually does.  Try some examples on a piece of paper.  How many bytes do you copy to user?  What value is returned?

Comment: It works with return value of Zero, flooding stops.Thanks. There are no updated tutorials for learning drivers. Share if you know any.

Comment: Returning zero may stop the infinite loop, but that doesn't mean it "works"; userspace will interpret this as an indication that end-of-file was reached and no bytes were read (copied from the kernel), which is not true.  A `proc_read` function needs to follow the usual behavior of the `read` system call and return the number of bytes read into the buffer.

Comment: I must also point out that you have a potentially serious security vulnerability: your `proc_read` function will copy `my_flag` number of bytes into the user's buffer, even when that's greater than the number `count` which they requested.  That will most likely overflow their buffer and overwrite something that shouldn't be overwritten.  It seems to me that the number of bytes you copy, and the value returned from `proc_read`, should simply be `count` (which you have already ensured will not exceed `my_flag`).

Comment: You ask about "drivers" but a proc file is not a device driver.  However, there is a reasonable-looking tutorial at https://devarea.com/linux-kernel-development-creating-a-proc-file-and-interfacing-with-user-space/#.XkacDel7lhE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The write function should return the number of bytes you processed.

In your case, 'proc_write_flag' function is returning 'ret' which is 0.
which means it will be invoked repeatedly until you process 'count' number of bytes from 'ubuf'

Similarly, 'proc_read_flag' should return the number of bytes you wrote into 'data'. In your case it is returning 0 (len)

There are other problems in 'proc_write_flag' function.

'buf' array isn't initialize and casting 'buf'(address) to int will not give you the expected answer.

Start with this http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2013/12/creating-directory-under-proc-in-kernel.html

Then look into kstrtol() function.